# MySQL - errno 150: "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, constraints

I am using MySQL on my practice task in tutorial, yet I have a problem on creating a table with error "incorrect constraint".

Please have a look and suggest me how I can fix it. Thank you!

*A course-offering is a course offered in a specific semester
*Students will enrol in course-offerings, not courses
*Lecturer is assigned to course-offerings, not courses

```
CREATE TABLE `students` (
  `student_id` char(8) NOT NULL,
  `max_load` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`student_id`)
)
CREATE TABLE `courses` (
`course_code` char(8) NOT NULL,
`course_title` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`course_code`)
)
CREATE TABLE `lecturers` (
  `lecturer_id` char(8) NOT NULL,
  `lecturer_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`lecturer_id`)
)

CREATE TABLE `course_offerings` (
  `course_code` char(8) NOT NULL,
  `semester` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `year` year(4) NOT NULL,
  `lecturer_id` char(8) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`course_code`,`semester`,`year`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`course_code`) REFERENCES `courses` (`course_code`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`lecturer_id`) REFERENCES `lecturers` (`lecturer_id`)
)

CREATE TABLE `enrolment` (
`student_id` char(8) NOT NULL,
`course_code` char(8) NOT NULL,
`semester` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
`year` year(4) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`student_id`,`course_code`,`semester`,`year`),
FOREIGN KEY (`student_id`) REFERENCES students(`student_id`),
FOREIGN KEY (`course_code`) REFERENCES course_offerings(`course_code`),
FOREIGN KEY (`semester`) REFERENCES course_offerings(`semester`),
FOREIGN KEY (`year`) REFERENCES course_offerings(`year`)
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to have composite foreign key on `enrolment`? If it's the case, the following may be what you want.

```
CREATE TABLE `enrolment` (
    `student_id` char(8) NOT NULL,
    `course_code` char(8) NOT NULL,
    `semester` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
    `year` year(4) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`student_id`,`course_code`,`semester`,`year`),
FOREIGN KEY (`student_id`) 
     REFERENCES students(`student_id`),
FOREIGN KEY (`course_code`, `semester`, `year`)  
     REFERENCES course_offerings(`course_code`, `semester`, `year`))
```

I'd suggest you to create an `id` column in course_offerings and make it primary key, keeping course_code, semester and year combined UNIQUE key. Use this `id` as a foreign key so you will need 1 column instead of 3 columns.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will follow your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You need check your type of column between source and destination table 
`semester` tinyint NOT NULL,
`year` year NOT NULL,
vs 
`semester` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
`year` year(4) NOT NULL,

Comment: it doesnt help even after I check that all. yet the length (4), (8) on year and tinyint ... are auto added by the wizard as they are the default length of such types.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs if you have defined relations and delete a table that has a relationship with another one.After that try to import deleted table back.[image]

You can drop the relation by these steps of the related table and after importing the table create a relation back

Answer (score -1):

how about this?

```
ALTER TABLE `kategori_transportasi` ADD FOREIGN KEY ( `no_ktp_pemesan` ) REFERENCES `tbl_daftar_customer` (
`no_ktp_pemesan`);
```

MySQL said: Documentation

```
#1005 - Can't create table `kuda_express`.`#sql-d64_216` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (Details…)
```